# Pytorch LSTM vs LSTMCell

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, lstm-stateful

What is the difference between [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm) and [LSTMCell](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstmcell) in Pytorch (currently version 1.1)? It seems that LSTMCell is a special case of LSTM (i.e. with only one layer, unidirectional, no dropout).

Then, what's the purpose of having both implementations? Unless I'm missing something, it's trivial to use an LSTM object as an LSTMCell (or alternatively, it's pretty easy to use multiple LSTMCells to create the LSTM object)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you can emulate one by another, the reason for having them separate is efficiency.

[`LSTMCell`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstmcell) is a cell that takes arguments:

- Input of shape batch × input dimension;
- A tuple of LSTM hidden states of shape batch x hidden dimensions.

It is a straightforward implementation of the equations.

[`LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm) is a layer applying an LSTM cell (or multiple LSTM cells) in a "for loop", but the loop is heavily optimized using cuDNN. Its input is

- A three-dimensional tensor of inputs of shape batch × input length × input dimension;
- Optionally, an initial state of the LSTM, i.e., a tuple of hidden states of shape batch × hidden dim (or tuple of such tuples if the LSTM is bidirectional)

You often might want to use the LSTM cell in a different context than apply it over a sequence, i.e. make an LSTM that operates over a tree-like structure. When you write a decoder in sequence-to-sequence models, you also call the cell in a loop and stop the loop when the end-of-sequence symbol is decoded.

Comment: Your answer successfully helped me understand how to implement this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00148.pdf. I was having trouble understanding the decoder portion, but now that I know to use a single cell, I can do it. Thank you.

Comment: LSTMcell is also very usefull when applying to sequences of different lengths, as this can be handled by an outer for loop instead of the optimized one.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show some specific examples:

```py
# LSTM example:
>>> rnn = nn.LSTM(10, 20, 2)
>>> input = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
>>> h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
>>> c0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
>>> output, (hn, cn) = rnn(input, (h0, c0))
# LSTMCell example:
>>> rnn = nn.LSTMCell(10, 20)
>>> input = torch.randn(3, 10)
>>> hx = torch.randn(3, 20)
>>> cx = torch.randn(3, 20)
>>> output = []
>>> for i in range(6):
        hx, cx = rnn(input[i], (hx, cx))
        output.append(hx)
```

The key difference:

1. LSTM: the argument `2`, stands `num_layers`, number of recurrent layers. There are `seq_len * num_layers=5 * 2` cells. **No loop but more cells.**
2. LSTMCell: in `for` loop (`seq_len=5` times), each output of `ith` instance will be input of `(i+1)th` instance. There is only one cell, **Truly Recurrent**

If we set `num_layers=1` in LSTM or add one more LSTMCell, the codes above will be the same.

Obviously, It is easier to apply parallel computing in LSTM.

Comment: This is wrong. In the LSTM case, the weights are still shared time steps.

Comment: @Kaleidophon Weights are shared in all RNN's cells like RNN, LSTM, GRU. But I'm comparing LSTM and LSTMCell. LSTM has more cells, so can apply parallel computing, and Cell can only compute with loops

Comment: LSTMCell takes (inputs, (h_0,c_0)) -> ((batch, input_size) , ((batch, hidden_size), (batch, hidden_size)) ) OR ( input_size , (hidden_size, hidden_size) ). Your input shape in the loop isn't right.